# Extension Sub-Forum

Tags: discussion, feature-request, extensions

Why don't we start a sub forum that is specifically for questions relating to magento extensions?  Instead of closing questions on the main forum, etc.

Comment: Is an dedicated extension tag not enough for this?

Comment: Like I'm the first person in the magento community thinking in a granular way :)

Comment: most of us know stackexchange well enough, to not think about impossible solutions^^
Therefore we try to solve such things with the features we have, and a strong one is the Tags feature.
But yeah, it sure is not easy for people who are used to a Forum.

Comment: Ok.  Is there a point to this?  I already accepted Marius's answer.

Comment: no problem, he actually mentioned that we cant create a sub forum, so his answer is still valid :)
If you are interested to read more about what creating an "Area" on stackexchange involves, I suggest you to read http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: As I said.  I accepted.  As in I understand the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't start a subforum because we cannot. We are not in charge of creating websites on SE. And I doubt someone will agree in making such a sub-website because there will be a waste of time. here will be a lot of unanswered questions.
And extension developers should offer support for their work. If they don't offer support by email I doubt they will offer support on a SE website.
As for the closed questions about third party modules and you think you can answer one, just vote to reopen or flag it for moderator attention saying you have an answer and they will be reopened.

Comment: You are right, there would be a lot of unanswered questions.  My point was more from a community standpoint of users of extensions helping other users.